Laravel project fails to connect to database when using PHP artisan serve but works with MAMP
I have a Laravel project set up on my MacBook and I'm encountering an issue with connecting to the database when using PHP artisan serve. Here's the problem:
When I access the project via localhost/project_name/public, everything works fine, and database connection is also working fine.
However, when I try to use php artisan serve and access the project via http://127.0.0.1:8000 or http://localhost:8000, I encounter the following error:

Here are the relevant sections of my configuration:
.env File
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my_db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root


database.php file
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    ...
]


Here are the troubleshooting steps I've already taken. But nothing works for me
1.Cleared configuration cache using commands like
php artisan config:clear 
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:cache 
php artisan optimize


Deleted the cache files located at /bootstrap/cache/.
Tried changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 in the .env file.

Note: I am not using MAMP's default ports. Instead using 80 & 3306
Despite these attempts, the issue persists. I suspect there might be a configuration issue with MAMP or my macOS settings. Can anyone suggest a solution or further troubleshooting steps? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

First execute flush privileges; and test, if not worked, check if can you connect with another mysql user or not (you need to define user first)

@MohammadSalehi I already tried to create a new user in MySQL and given all privileges. That new user also works fine when I access the project with localhost/project_name/public. But the same error when accessing via 127.0.0.1:8000

The default MAMP MySQL port might be 8889, not the standard 3306.
Can you try changing it to the 8889?

I am not using MAMP's default ports instead I am using 80 & 3306

Are you able to connect to the database directly with any third-party client like Dbeaver, MySQL workbench, or anything else?

Also, ensure that the pdo_mysql PHP extension is enabled. MAMP usually enables this by default, but it's worth checking. You can create a PHP info file to check loaded extensions.

Can you post error logs here?
Check both Laravel's and MySQL's error logs for any relevant error messages. Laravel's log can be found in storage/logs, and MAMP's MySQL log can typically be found in /Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err.
